# How to open piped path with text editor?

Tags: bash

I want to do something like this:

```
which some_script | gedit
```

If I do this, `gedit` just open New document, instead of `/some/path/some_script`.

The best thing I managed to do is:

```
gedit $(which some_script)
```

but I don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert input to arguments, use `xargs`:

```
some command | xargs gedit
```

Since you "don't like" the correct method, be careful of spaces in filenames and the like.

Just so you know, the [most suitable way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) is:

```
gedit "$(command -v some_script)"
```